# How do I compile format junkie?

Tags: compiling

The `ppa:hakermania/format-junkie` is down, at least for me, is it possible to compile format junkie in 11.10? If so, how?

This is the list of files I have:

```
about.cpp                   error_logs.h          main.cpp
about.h                     error_logs.ui         mainwindow.cpp
about.ui                    formatjunkie.pro      mainwindow.h
audio_video_properties.cpp  glob.h                mainwindow.ui
audio_video_properties.h    icons.qrc             Pictures
audio_video_properties.ui   image_properties.cpp  preferences.cpp
data                        image_properties.h    preferences.h
error_logs.cpp              image_properties.ui   preferences.ui
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I am hakermania)

Format Junkie official PPA is now located at: https://launchpad.net/~format-junkie-team/+archive/release and the available versions are for 12.04 and 12.10 only, so if these do not work for you, then you will need to compile the source code for your system (sorry for this but we cannot add support for the latest 5 ubuntu releases, that would be a lot more work for us in each of the releases). Compiling Format Junkie with the files you have should be as simple as:

```
qmake formatjunkie.pro
make
```

but make sure you have all the build dependencies (check the file `debian/control` located at the `.debian.tar.gz` archive).

Comment: hi hakermania thanks for your reply, after installing the dependencies I get this error:uic: Error in line 129, column 29 : Unexpected attribute theme
uic: Error in line 394, column 34 : Unexpected attribute theme

Comment: You must be using different *U*ser *I*nterface *C*ompiler than me. Mine is 4.8.1 (found with `uic -v`). This error is cause from previous versions of UIC. You may edit the .ui files and remove all the `iconset theme` entries. This should work.

Comment: Thanks it compiled, without icons but compiled

Comment: Glad to know. You should know by now that by not updating your system at least once a year you will not be able to use the latest software so easily.