# Format junkie package not found, even after adding PPA

Tags: apt, 16.04, ppa, software-sources, format-conversion

I have installed the noobslab PPA and ran `sudo apt-get update`, but when I attempt `sudo apt-get install formatjunkie`, it says that the package can't be located. I'm wondering how to proceed in order to get formatjunkie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noobslab PPA you've added has formatjunkie for only 14.04 Trusty. It doesn't provide the package for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus). Check it here https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/apps?field.series_filter=xenial

If you want to get it, you need to compile it yourself. To see how to do that, check this question

- [How do I compile format junkie?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190976/how-do-i-compile-format-junkie)